# How can I show more than 50K records on UI as the SOQL limit is 50000 only?

Tags: lightning-web-components, soql, batch, governorlimits

How can I show more than 50K records on UI as the SOQL limit is 50000 only AND I want to them on UI without pagination or anything?

Comment: Not a good idea to display such large number of records, but you can do this via lazy loading. There are many ways to do this. Example: lightning-datatable has `enable-infinite-loading` property and `onloadmore` event to accomplish this.

Comment: but how to get the data from apex as we can only query 50k records only in soql.

Comment: You can't overcome that SOQL limit. Instead, you would need to use `onloadmore` and invoke apex to query limited # of records using `OFFSET`. Google search will get you plenty of articles and code sample.

Comment: you can use readonly annotation to query 100k records in reaonly mode.   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm.     hope you find your answer.please  dont use this platform to disucss interview question.  genuine questins with genuine  efforts before asking question  is appreciated here

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea that display more than 50k records on any UI, neither the browser can handle them or the user can read/use them.

If your user wants handling that scale of data, you may export the data from Salesforce using tools like Data Loader, give the csv or Excel file to the user and import them if the user changes the data.

Technically, if you really want to retrieve more that 50k records to the UI, you can retrieve multiple times from the backend.

Comment: Actually I have got this question in an Interview where the interviewer wanted to display 1 lac records in an LWC Component. So I am curious about how to do this?